# How to solve this Predicate logic derivation

Tags: logic, proof

I want to derive the following:

∀x(Fx ↔ (¬Gx ∨ ¬Hx)). ¬∀x(Gx ∧ Hx) → ∃x(Ix ∧ ¬Gx) ∴ ∃xFx → ∃x(Ix ∧ Fx)

This is my attempt:

[image]

Any suggestions as to how I continue and derive this? I cannot figure out how to continue
Thank you

EDIT: These are the inference rules as well as the derivation rules and assumptions:

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify what rules of inference are you using and include the proof checker website ?

Comment: @F.Zer  I have edited it to show above. The proof checker is called Elogic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have Elogic software, but perhaps this gives you a rough guide about the proof. I used some of @Mauro Allegranza excellent suggestions.

You assume ∃xFx and then assume ¬∃x(Ix ∧ Fx) in order to use **Indirect Proof** (your system calls this rule **Indirect Derivation**).

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask do you know where I can find a guide to the definitions you have used? @F.Zer

Comment: You are welcome. Here http://proofs.openlogicproject.org is the proof checker I used in the proof. In the right side of this webpage, there is a reference of the rules used.